# Python Sorting and Organising

Tags: python, list, sorting, text-files

I'm trying to sort data from a file and not quiet getting what i need.  I have a text file with race details ( name placement( ie 1,2,3).  I would like to be able to organize the data by highest placement first and also alphabetically by name.  I can do this if i split the lines but then the name and score will not match up.

Any help and suggestion would be very welcomed, I've hit that proverbial wall.

My apologies ( first time user for this site , and python noob, steep learning curve ) Thank you for your suggestions , i really do appreciate the help.

```
comp=[]

results = open('d:\\test.txt', 'r')


for line in results:
    line=line.split()
    # (name,score)= line.split()
    comp.append(line)
    sorted(comp)

results.close()
print (comp)
```

Test file was in this format:
Jones 2
Ranfel 7
Peterson 5
Smith 1
Simons 9
Roberts 4
McDonald 3
Rogers 6
Elliks 8
Helm 10

Comment: It's nearly impossible to help you without you posting your code and a sample of the text file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with everyone who has down-voted this question for being badly posed. However, I'm in a good mood so I'll try and at least steer you in the right direction:

Let's assume your text file looks like this:

```
Name,Placement
D,1
D,2
C,1
C,3
B,1
B,3
A,1
A,4
```

I suggest importing the data and sorting it using Pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data
# Replace <FULL_PATH_OF FILE> with something like C:/Data/RaceDetails.csv
# The first row is automatically used for column names
data=pd.read_csv("<FULL_PATH_OF_FILE>")

# Sort the data
sorted_data=data.sort(['Placement','Name'])

# Create a re-indexed data frame if you so desire
sorted_data_new_index=sorted_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This gives me:

```
Name Placement
A    1
B    1
C    1
D    1
D    2 
B    3
C    3
A    4
```

I'll leave you to figure out the rest..

Answer (score 0):

As @Jack said, I am very limited to how I can help if you don't post code or the txt file. However, I've run into a similar problem before, so I know the basics (again, will need code/files before I can give an exact type-this-stuff answer!)

You can either develop an algorithm yourself, or use the built-in `sorted` feature

Put the names and scores in a list (or dictionary) such as:

```
name_scores = [['Matt', 95], ['Bob', 50], ['Ashley', 100]]
```

and then call `sorted(name_scores)` and it will sort by names: `[['Ashley', 100], ['Bob', 50], ['Matt', 95]]`